# Dereferencing a pointer aliased from another of an incompatible type

Tags: c, type-punning

If I do this assignment

```
float x = 16.8;
unsigned int i = *(unsigned int*) &x;
```

What will be the value of the variable `i`? What it is the logic of this assignment?

Comment: Undefined behaviour, strict aliasing rule applies.

Comment: its a integer therefore no decimal points. Also why not test it in a compiler simply? Will lead to UB

Comment: You should use a union, apparently, or else the behavior will be undefined. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) for more info.

Comment: @amanuel2 Testing undefined behaviour in C is pointless, because results are *undefined*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a code like this, you could have seen the answer **in your precise case**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{    
    float x = 1;
    unsigned int i = *(unsigned int*) &x;
    printf("%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

---

This type of assignment is illegal, by casting a pointer to a **`float`** into a pointer to an **`unsigned int`**, then dereferencing it, you are against the **Strict Aliasing Rule**.

As it was said in the comments, there is no strict answer.
Even if with a rounded `x` like :

```
float x = 16;
```

You will probably not have an expected `i = 16`.

In most cases, your code will seem correct, you will not be warned or anything, and you code will run. *So be careful!*